# No default repositories in Qt Maintenance Tool

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.4

I recently installed Qt 5.5 and its MaintenanceTool (MaintenanceTool.exe). The default repositories were working, but after one day, my MaintenanceTool suddenly reported that no repositories were set.

I can temporarily enter individual repositories in the MaintenanceTool, but I would like to get the default repos set.

Why are they gone?
How can I set the default repositories again?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31685711/2778484

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update GCC in MinGW on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865319/how-to-update-gcc-in-mingw-on-windows)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The Maintenance Tool is doing crazy things since the recent updates made by Qt team.

The only solution I know is:

- Add the next temporary repository in "Settings":

  Windows: http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/windows/x86/online_repository/

  Mac: http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/mac/x64/online_repository/
- Now, you can update the Qt components and you should see a new update for the Maintenance Tool.

If everything goes well, the Maintenance Tool will be fixed.

Comment: As of April 2, 2017 the repository is:
[http://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/root/qt/](http://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/root/qt/)

Comment: As of July 20, 2017, it seems the new repository URL is `http://download.qt-project.org/online/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/root/qt`

Comment: For linux: http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/linux/x64/online_repository/

Comment: It's crazy to think that this issue is still here in Qt 5.12. I'm baffled as to why they don't fix it because it makes the tool unusable (if you're not lucky to find this post here).

Comment: @rbaleksandar totally agree.

Comment: Its still crazy ----   this issue is in Qt 5.14.2 also. Why they dont just fix it

Comment: As of May 3, 2021, The problem persits with 5.14.2. The repository here works : http://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/root/qt/

Answer (score 9):

**Note:**  The download speed of the default repo by Qt is **quite slow** (usually limited to 2mbps).
So you might want to use official mirrors to get much **higher** download speeds.
Here is some magic to quickly get those repo addresses:

1. Open the following url (which contains online repo components of Qt:
   http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/windows/x86/online_repository/qt/
   You'll see some files in that directory
2. Click on "Details" on the right side of any of those files.
   This will show mirror links of the file such as:
   http://ftp2.nluug.nl/languages/qt/online/qt5/windows/x86/online_repository/qt/1.0.0meta.7z
3. Cut the right side of any of those urls to make it end with `online_repository`.
   It should be something like this afterward:
   http://ftp2.nluug.nl/languages/qt/online/qt5/windows/x86/online_repository

And here we go! Now you can use that url as a repository which has higher download speeds.

Answer (score 3):

As of today (2017 oct. 30) the Mac repo url http://download.qt-project.org/online/qtsdkrepository/mac_x64/root/qt worked for me

1. Manually added the repository as a custom repo.
2. Updated (only the maintenance tool was updated at that time it seems).
3. Relaunched the maintenance tool.
4. Deleted the custom repo because many repos were present in the default repositories list, then quit the maintenance tool.
5. Relaunched the maintenance tool and updated normally.

**BTW:** I used the offline installer for the first install on my Mac.

Comment: I just (August 2019) successfully followed these steps to add components to a Qt 5.5 installation on macOS. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

26th January 2022 : If you are using an old maintenance tool, you need to update the maintenance tool first by adding the repo 'http://download.qt-project.org/online/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/desktop/tools_maintenance' under user defined repository following the above described steps and selecting "update components". Now you can add/remove the components such as QtCharts, Qt3D etc.