# How to install <QtCharts> on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qtcharts

I have a hard time getting QtCharts to work on my computer. I think I am missing the concept. I have Qt 5.8 installed on my computer. I am using visual studio for all my development. After googling for a while I have noticed people say that you need to import the QtChart module but I do not understand:

1) Why QtCharts is not a part of my Qt installation in the first place?

2) And if I do have to install it, how do I do it on windows with VS 2017?

If someone could please clear this up for me I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, [it is different](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html).  It is available as an addon with a different license.  Either a commercial license or GPL.  Or to put it another way, they want you to pay for it, unless they can't make you :)  They can make you, looks like $3540 for a short-term license.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is old but I had the same question. **To install the QtCharts Module** (or any other module) **here is what you want to do:**

1. go to your Qt Installation Folder, find and open the MaintenanceTool.exe
2. skip the first page
3. press "settings" and open the "repository" tab
4. select "user defined repositories" and press "add"
5. now in the new line check the "use" Checkbox and copy an URL to a Qt repo (see this stackoverflow question [No default repositories in Qt Maintenance Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428931/no-default-repositories-in-qt-maintenance-tool)) into the "Repository" column (leave the rest blank)
   [image: entering a suitable repo Qt URL]
6. press "ok"
7. select "add or remove component" and press next
8. now under Qt->Qt 5.8 you see all installed addons, check the boxes you Need
   [image]

Comment: I've already used Qt Maintenance but no module error is still there, can you help?