# Qt 5.9 QtWebKit not installed

Tags: qt, qml, qtwebkit, qwebview

I just installed Qt Creator 5.9 and 5.3. I decided to somehow copy the plugin/module/source files for QtWebKit from 5.3 to 5.9. Basically, I "ported it", but without any success. It just keeps bringing up the error:

QT module(s) not installed: webkit

What version of Qt should I use in order to build iOS, Android and Windows mobile applications with QtWebView? I can't wrap my head around how this works. If anyone can direct me to a working environment with QML QtWebView module fully installed or can tell me what I missed in my "porting", I would really appreciate it since I really can't find any solution to this problem, no matter how much time I spend searching on google.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT: module "QtWebView" is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450333/qt-module-qtwebview-is-not-installed)

Comment: @MohammadKanan: Though the question might be a duplicate, since the answer seems to satisfy the OP of your linked question, IMHO it is not an answer to the question. Instead of explaining the error and how to solve it, the answer seems to state, there would be a more powerful alternative for some platforms - and not more. Since according to the answer it is only for *some platforms* and this question seems to be about multiple platforms, the answer in your linked question does not necessarily help. Having the link in this question however, I think is a good thing.

Comment: @derM, as you know QtWebKit is not in Qt anymore and replaced by `QWebEngine`, while I thought this was a good reason to indicate the duplicate solution, I also noticed it has enough info considering multi platforms. I dare no provide answer for deprecated software ... I really also think its pointless anyone do that .. you just can't be sure of a solution lifting QtWebKit to your latest Qt version ...

Comment: Yeah, and that should be part of an answer. Without that, the answer is talking about something completely unrelated. It might be that things are treated in the comments, but the comments are not part of the answer and you can't assume that someone reads all the comments when looking for the answer.

Comment: [Qt WebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html)