# How can I install a Qt Module and use it in my project

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-mobility

I'm trying to use the QtContacts module. I'm using ubuntu artful and qt 5.10

I've tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install qml-module-qtcontacts
```

and this:

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-qtcontacts-plugin
```

I put in the .pro file: `QT += androidextras contacts`, but I get the message: `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: contacts`

I also tried this answer: [How to install a missing Qt module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200094/how-to-install-a-missing-qt-module)

But the module doesn't appear in the modules list:

[image]

What did I miss?

QtVersion:
[image]

I downloaded the qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.2-online.run in this link: https://www.qt.io/download

Comment: When you install using apt-get it is different when using an installer that provides Qt, they are 2 different qt.

Comment: How have you installed Qt?

Comment: I'm using qt 5.10.0. I Updated the question with some more information.

Comment: I downloaded the installer in this link: https://www.qt.io/download

Comment: Try [Package: [qml-module-qtcontacts](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/qml-module-qtcontacts) under `artful` ... check the dependencies!

Comment: @MohammadKanan Thanks for the link. I checked the dependencies and they are all installed.

Answer (score 1):

I would try fetching from [here](https://github.com/KDE/android-qt-mobility), and install with `configure/make/make install`.

Looking at [this documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt-mobility/index.html), it seems that there is a [Contacts API](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt-mobility/contacts.html), and a [Contacts QML plugin](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt-mobility/qml-contacts.html).

Looking at the pro file in [this example](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt-mobility/samplephonebook.html), there is no `contact` module appended to `QT`, but a `CONFIG` entry like this:

```
 CONFIG += mobility
 MOBILITY = contacts
```

Comment: In the github link you shared the last commit was made 7 years ago. Are you sure this version should compile successfully?

Comment: I tried make the project from github, but I got the messages: `recipe for target '../../build/Debug/QtSystemInfo/qsysteminfo_linux.o' failed` and `recipe for target 'sub-systeminfo-make_default' failed`. Thanks for your tips, they were very valuable and helped me a lot. I'm trying to install the QtMobility some how. Maybe the problem is my ubuntu version. It seems the qtmobility was not released in artful: launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/+source/qtmobility